# Checking if user is logged in (session) issue

Tags: php

I have created a .php file called "checklogged.php" and I include it on every page that is only accessible to logged in users by doing:

```
<?php include_once ('checklogged.php'); ?>
```

The file itself:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_SESSION['ID'])) {
echo 'not set';
}

?>
```

It's currently just echoing it if my ID is not set.

The problem is that it's echoing it even if I am logged in and my ID is set!

For example - I am on my user dashboard and it's echoing out that it's not set. But it IS set because I am logged in and I am actually displaying my ID on the dashboard:

```
<tr>
      <td><strong>Account ID</strong></td>
      <td><?php echo $_SESSION['ID']?></td>
</tr>
```

Which is working just fine there. However on the top of the page I still see 'not set'. So how the hell is it working in the table and is not set in the checklogged.php?!

And this is where I am setting the ID (when user logs in):

```
 $_SESSION['ID'] = $line["ID"];
```

Comment: did you remember `session_start()`? I'm betting a shiny new penny on "not".

Comment: I am already starting a session in my `header.php` (to check if I should display log in or log out button). So when I try to start it in this `checklogged.php` file, then it says it's already started. Because they are both included in my `dashboard.php`.

Comment: What happens if you refresh your Dashboard? Is it possible that you are performing the *Login logic* after including `checklogged.php`? Then the id will not be set in `checklogged.php` during the request you are actually Login in.

Comment: Stays the same when I refresh it. Problem must be that I am doing `<?php include_once ('header.php'); ?>` and `<?php include_once ('checklogged.php'); ?>` which means I cant start a session in the second file because it's started in the `header.php`.

Comment: `A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\checklogged.php on line 3` Oh I guess it's just a notice not an error, but how can I hide this?

Comment: @fidtal use `@session_start()` to surpress warnings. But if the file throws that notice, it should be able to Access the id since the session has obviously been detected as "started"...

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed. Just hid the notice now with @.